# Selenium C# How to use variable in JavaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I'am using JavaScriptExecutor in my Selenium tests and it looks like below:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string Pixels = "600";
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style='transform: translateX(600px);'", DatesSlider);
```

I would like to use variable Pixels istead of 600 in JS script but I don't know how to do that.
Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$` and `{}` with variable. This should work.

```
 string Pixels = "600";
 js.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].style='transform: translateX({Pixels}px);'", DatesSlider);
```